# Spring overriding properties file in ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring

I'm fetching application messages from resource bundle using `ResourceBundleMessageSource`. This is how my application is: In my resources folder, I have a base properties files, say `messages_en.properties`. And then under the resources folder, I also have other customer specific folders each having their own `messages_en.properties` files. So this is how the folder hierarchy looks like:

```
src/main/resources:
    |
     --- messages_en.properties
    |
     --- customerA
            |
             --- messages_en.properties
```

Now, what I want to do is, when I do something like `bundle.getMessage(key, ...);` I want to check the properties file for that particular customer. If the properties file has the key, then display the message. If not, I need to fetch the information from the base properties file which is directly under `src/main/resources`.

How do I do this? How do I check both the properties files? Is it possible? I'm new to Spring, so I apologize in advance if my question sounds silly.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to write this yourself, as Spring won't support this very specific use case. Probably you can write your own class that has 2 `ResourceBundleMessageSource`, one of the customer and the generic one, if you don't find the string in the customer one, you fallback to the generic one.

Comment: @Augusto Thanks. One more question. I'm having a maven project. Is it possible to fetch the resource files from the project's parent project?